# Using groupby to get % of subtotal by group

Tags: python, transform

```
data = {'car': ['ford', 'ford','ford','toyota', 'honda', 'toyota','kia', 'nissan','honda'],
        'colorblue': [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
        'colorred': [0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
        'colorblack': [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0],
        'volume': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

df['colorbluepercent'] = 100 * df['colorblue'] / df.groupby('car')['colorblue'].transform('sum')
df['colorredpercent'] = 100 * df['colorred'] / df.groupby('car')['colorred'].transform('sum')
df['colorblackpercent'] = 100 * df['colorblack'] / df.groupby('car')['colorblack'].transform('sum')
cargroup = df.groupby('car').sum()
cargroup
```

Newish programmer here. I am trying to get the % of total but within the group itself. For instance, Colorblue should be 66% for ford (2/3) instead of 100%.  I also tried using the volume column as a denominator, as:

```
df['colorbluepercent'] = (df.groupby('car') ['colorblue'].transform('sum'))/(df.groupby('car') ['volume'].transform('sum'))
```

Is there a way to get the % that will give me the groupedby % of subtotal?
Additionally, this is a sample dataset. The real one has many columns. One thought I had originally is:

```
feature_cols = df.select_dtypes([np.number]).columns 
n = len(feature_cols)
append_str = '_percent'
feature_cols2 = [col + append_str for col in feature_cols]

feature_cols = str(feature_cols)
feature_cols2 = str(feature_cols2)

while n > 0:
  df[feature_cols2] = 100 * df[{feature_cols}] / df.groupby('car')[{feature_cols}].transform('sum')
  n=n-1
```

But I found without str conversion (I also tried tuple) I got an unhashable error, but once I added the str or tuple it indicates the column names are not in the df.

KeyError: "None of [Index(['Index(['colorblue', 'colorred', 'colorblack', 'volume', 'colorblue%',\n       'colorred%', 'colorblack%'],\n      dtype='object')'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

So if there is a solution for obtaining % of total for each group that allows me to feed all columns as a list in, that would be best solution.

Answer (score 0):

One convenient way is to use `value_counts(normalize=True)` in your groupby, which returns the count of each value divided by the total count in each group:

```
>>> df.groupby("car").colorblue.value_counts(normalize=True)
car     colorblue
ford    1            0.666667
        0            0.333333
honda   1            1.000000
kia     0            1.000000
nissan  0            1.000000
toyota  0            0.500000
        1            0.500000
Name: colorblue, dtype: float64
```

You can calculate the proportions on as many columns as you want, for example:

```
>>> df.groupby("car")[["colorred", "colorblue"]].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm wanting. I'm wanting more the sum of the 1s and 0s divided by total count.  This is instead the unique count % of each value. I could filter to just '1' results for one, but I'm working with a multi column dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this resolved. My problem was that I was trying to add the % of total columns to the existing dataframe. The problem is much easier if you start with an already aggregated DF.

```
df['volume'] = 1
out_df = df.groupby('car').sum().reset_index()
out_df['colorbluepercent'] = out_df.colorblue/out_df.volume
out_df['colorredpercent'] = out_df.colorred/out_df.volume
out_df['colorblackpercent'] = out_df.colorblack/out_df.volume
out_df
```